# Clearing cache using AppCache and window.applicationCache

Tags: caching

I could inspect the status of the entire cache using window.applicationCache and the updateready event via AppCache.Is there a way to see if the particular resource we're concerned with is cached or not and, if so is there a programmatic solution of clearing the cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear from [the API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#application-cache-api) that inspecting the cache in that way or that clearing it are possible. I have also not seen proprietary ways of doing so, but they may exist.